# Appending to an h5 file using deepdish

Tags: python, h5py

Can anyone please help me append a list of dictionaries to an already existing h5 file using deepdish? I have been searching on the internet but I couldn't come up with any solutions.

Comment: You will have to add more details.  I am familiar with HDF5 and h5py, but have no idea what you want to do (or how to help you). For example, what is deepdish? Have you written any code? Note: I think you really want to add **datasets** to your file. h5py can do this. Also it uses Python dictionary syntax to return dataset/group names and objects, but they aren't stored as 'dictionaries' in HDF5.

Comment: Sorry for being so cryptic. Well deepdish is one of the newer packages which you can now use to store dictionaries and other stuff directly without pre-processing them(the package itself has functions for processing them for i/o). So my command was deepdish.io.save(filename, dictionary, compression=None). I wanted to write to the same h5 file I had created earlier. I searched online and apparently there's a lot of processing required to store a dictionary in an h5 file. I was looking to bypass them by using the command above. But I don't know how to append to the same file using deepdish

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary has simple key,value pairs, it's relatively simple to convert it to a NumPy array (with the help of an intermediate list). To demonstrate, I wrote a short example that creates a dictionary mapping letters to their ordinal value, then converting and writing to a HDF5 dataset.

This example creates 2 datasets:

1. `ex_dict` is created from a NumPy nd.array (which has single dtype). All data is saved as strings.
2. `ex_dict2` is created from a NumPy recarray (which can have multiple dtypes). Keys are saved as strings, and the values are saved as integers.

See below.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

ex_dict = {chr(i):i for i in range(97,97+26)}
arr = np.array(list(ex_dict.items()))
print(arr.dtype)
arr = np.array(list(ex_dict.items()),dtype='S3')
print(arr.dtype)

recarr = np.recarray(shape=(26,), dtype=[ ('key','S3'), ('value',int) ] )
recarr['key'] = np.array(list(ex_dict.keys()),dtype='S3')
recarr['value'] = np.array(list(ex_dict.values()))
print(recarr.dtype)

with h5py.File('SO_67704593.h5','w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset('ex_dict1',data=arr)
    h5f.create_dataset('ex_dict2',data=recarr)
```

Notes on code above:
`dtype='S3'` in `np.array()` is workaround for a h5py limitation with NumPy Unicode characters (the default when you convert lists of strings into an array). I printed both dtypes so you can see the differences. Only the second array can be used to create the HDF5 dataset.

Use code below to read data from the datasets:

```
dict_from_ds1 = {} 
dict_from_ds2 = {}    
with h5py.File('SO_67704593.h5','r') as h5r:   
    for row in h5r['ex_dict1']:
        dict_from_ds1[row[0].decode('utf-8')] = row[1].decode('utf-8')
    for row in h5r['ex_dict2']:
        dict_from_ds2[row[0].decode('utf-8')] = row[1]

print (dict_from_ds1)        
print (dict_from_ds2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful reply. I was able to edit my h5 file by opening it in append mode using this code. Well, I'm looking forward to storing a dictionary having multiple key-value pairs which have different datatypes (all numpy arrays of different shapes). I saw the idea on recarray but I couldn't get that. And storing all the items in an ndarray causes errors. Could you please shed a bit more light on that?

Comment: Also, how do I extract my original data back from the S3 data type?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to create a dataset using a recarray of `dtype=(string, int)`. Dealing with key-value pairs where the values are numpy arrays of different shapes is a LOT MORE complicated. h5py supports variable length arrays. but with limitations: 1) array shape must be 1 dimension: `(#,)` or `(1,#)` (e.g. `shape=(3,4)` not allowed); 2) dataset is limited to the variable length array only -- cannot have mixed type with key as string and value as variable length array. There are ways to attack this, but no simple ways.

Comment: I added code to the example above that shows how to read from both datasets:  `ex_dict1` and `ex_dict2`. The trick is decoding the strings with `.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a follow-up based on the request in the comments (*'storing a dictionary having multiple key-value pairs which have different datatypes (all numpy arrays of different shapes'*).

As noted in my comments, having different array shapes presents challenges saving the data in 1 dataset. However, that can be overcome by using a different data schema: create 1 dataset for each dictionary key/value (numpy array) pair. The key is the dataset name, and the value array is saved in the dataset. This has the added benefit that different datasets can have different dtypes (floats, ints, or strings). I created an example to do this. (For simplicity, all arrays are floats in my example.)

See code below:

```
arr_dict = {}
dict_list = [ ('One:2x2', 2,2), ('Two:1x3', 1,3), ('Three:4x2', 4,2), 
              ('Four:2x5', 2,5), ('Five:10x10', 10,10) ]

for tup in dict_list:
    name, a0, a1 = tup[0], tup[1], tup[2]
    arr = np.random.random(a0*a1).reshape(a0,a1)
    arr_dict[name] = arr

with h5py.File('SO_67704593_arr.h5','w') as h5f:
    for key,arr in arr_dict.items():
        h5f.create_dataset(key,data=arr)
```

Code to retrieve the datasets and recreate the dictionary provided below:

```
get_arr_dict = {}
with h5py.File('SO_67704593_arr.h5','r') as h5r:
    for ds in h5r.keys():
        get_arr_dict[ds] = h5r[ds][:]
        
for k,v in get_arr_dict.items():
    print(k,':',v)
```